# Parse svg with R

Tags: r, svg, rvest

I want to turn svg graphs like net worth advantage here http://www.dotabuff.com/matches/2502387920 into a table with minutes of a game in one column and advantage in another.

I start with pretty obvious lines of code

```
library(rvest)
pic <- html("http://www.dotabuff.com/matches/2502387920") %>% html_node(xpath = "//svg")
```

Then I think the most useful information is in attribute d

```
pic %>% html_attr("d")
```

Finally, I get something like "m1234.8,2812.1,6.3004,3.6375,0,1.77-6.3004-3.6375z". I don't know how to interpret it.

Comment: The info used by dotabuff usually comes from an API (not sure if there an official API) here is one https://dota2api.readthedocs.io/en/latest/. I think it's an easy and clean path if you know how to access to that api beacuse if you want to do this several times the get html you'll have performance problems.

Answer (score 1):

**NOT TECHNICALLY AN ANSWER BUT TOO LARGE FOR A COMMENT**

That's because you're seeing the actual SVG local coordinates. Converting those back to real data is going to be ugly (if nigh impossible). Normally, I'd suggest just pulling the data from an XHR request, but that site does not make an XHR request for the data. They're actually using a Highcharts data obfuscation technique by embedding encoded data into some `<div>`s. Here's your data:

```
<div style="height: 260px" data-highchart="yes" data-encoded="*7JyYoFmc0JiO#7JCd5BXZiojIhJXZhJSfsICbldWZuRmI6snIl5WYixWZkJiOmFGbzVWfsIyc$lJXalNnI6s1ei4WYtVmI6ISQkZXYuRXYnVmIsIyYvx2byJiOiMSOyEUNyUjI]sIibldWY0lmdlN0bs9mciojIjMkMzMkMBJCLiYWasx2TwF2YpRXeioDMuQDL$iQHayV2co9GbkJiOw4CMsICbp5WZXlGZ0hmI6QDLiQWY0FmI6s1W2ADLxIjN#dxyWxIDMsIDMz0FLbFDOwwSL0kTOdxyWyQDMsMDNz0FLbNDMwwSM3kTXss1M#2ADL5UDOdxyW0IDMsUTN50FLbRDOwwiM4UDOdxyW1QDMsQTO20FLbZDMwwiN*4YTXsslN2ADL0gzMdxyW3IDMs0SMzkTXss1N4ADLtcjMy0FLbhDNwwSLyYjM]30FLblDMwwSLykTM00FLbljNwwSLyQzNy0FLbFDMyADLtEDNycTXssVMwgDM$s0SO0ATXssVMxQDMs0SM5czMdxyWxIDMwwSLxQTO00FLbFjM2ADLtEDNxgTX&amp;ssVMzIDMs0SMygTMdxyWxMDOwwSLxIDO20FLbFDN0ADLzEzN20FLbFTNwADL#0IjM50FLbFTN2ADL4IzN40FLbFjNyADL5ITN30FLbFjN4ADLxQDMxATXssVM]3QDMsEDN0kDMdxyWxgDMwwSM0IzMy0FLbFDO2ADLxUTM1ATXdxiItFmcrVmc@iozeiUmbhJGblRmI6YWYsNXZ91XXsISZ4RnchNnI6snI4FEepNnRvJXbhRnI&amp;6ICZ1JXY0l2buJCLiQ3bvxGdpBnRvJXbhRnI6ICdlFWbBRmdh5GdhdWZi0Xf" data-annotated="true"></div></div><div class="r-tab r-group-2" style="display:block; width: 100%"><div style="height: 260px" data-highchart="yes" data-encoded="}7JyYoFmc0JiO&amp;7JCd5BXZiojIhJXZhJSfsICbldWZuRmI6snIl5WYixWZkJiOmFGbzVWfsIyc]lJXalNnI6s1ei4WYtVmI6ISQkZXYuRXYnVmIsIyYvx2byJiOiMSOyEUNyUjI*sIibldWY0lmdlN0bs9mciojIjMkMzMkMBJCLiYWasx2TwF2YpRXeioDMuQDL$iQHayV2co9GbkJiOw4CMsICbp5WZXlGZ0hmI6QDLiQWY0FmI6s1W2ADL3ATX]ssVMyADLxYjNdxyWxgDMsEDM40FLbJDNwwyN0kTXss1MwADL2IzNdxyWzYDM]sEjNzQTXssFNyADLxUjM10FLbRDOwwSM3YjNdxyW1QDMsMTM00FLbZDMwwyN@2QTXsslN2ADLyMjNdxyW3IDMs0SMzUzMdxyW3gDMs0SM4EDNdxyW4QDMs0iM$0QTMdxyW5ADMs0CNykDMdxyW5YDMs0CNxUzNdxyWxAjMwwSLzMzNw0FLbFDM]4ADLtMzMyMTXssVMxQDMs0SNxMDOdxyWxIDMwwSL1QTN10FLbFjM2ADLtQTO#2kTXssVMzIDMs0SNyUzNdxyWxMDOwwSL2ADO10FLbFDN0ADLtIzM5YTXssVM]1ADMs0iNwATXssVM1YDMsEzN5MTXssVM2IDMsIzMwcTXssVM2gDMsQzM4ITX@ssVM3QDMsQTOzcTXssVM4ADMsQjN0ETXssVM4YDMsQjM4gTXdxiItFmcrVmc&amp;iozeiUmbhJGblRmI6YWYsNXZ91XXsISZ4RnchNnI6snI4FEepNnRvJXbhRnI#6ICZ1JXY0l2buJCLiQ3bvxGdpBnRvJXbhRnI6ICdlFWbBRmdh5GdhdWZi0Xf" data-annotated="true"></div></div><div class="r-tab r-group-3" style="display:block; width: 100%"><div style="height: 260px" data-highchart="yes" data-encoded="#7JyYoFmc0JiO@7JCd5BXZiojIhJXZhJSfsICbldWZuRmI6snIl5WYixWZkJiOmFGbzVWfsIyc$lJXalNnI6s1ei4WYtVmI6ISQkZXYuRXYnVmIsIyYvx2byJiOiMSOyEUNyUjI}sIibldWY0lmdlN0bs9mciojIjMkMzMkMBJCLiYWasx2TwF2YpRXeioDMuQDL$iQHayV2co9GbkJiOw4CMsICbp5WZXlGZ0hmI6QDLiQWY0FmI6s1W2ADLyQTM$dxyWxIDMsIDM40FLbFDOwwSL4ATOdxyWyQDMs0SMwQTXss1MwADLtgzMdxyW]zYDMscDNy0FLbRjMwwSOxATXssFN4ADLyMDO10FLbVDNwwiM1cTXsslNwADL#2QzNdxyW2YDMsQTO00FLbdjMwwSLycTNdxyW3gDMs0yN4gTXssFO0ADLtITM&amp;0UTXssVOwADLtIjM1cTXssVO2ADLtIjMxUTXssVMwIDMs0SM1kTOdxyWxADO}wwSL5YjMdxyWxEDNwwSLxYTO50FLbFjMwADLtEjNyATXssVMyYDMs0SMwUTO&amp;dxyWxMjMwwSL4cjMdxyWxMDOwwSLxEjM30FLbFDN0ADLyIzN00FLbFTNwADL@zATN30FLbFTN2ADL2MDNy0FLbFjNyADL2kTN20FLbFjN4ADLxETM1ETXssVM@3QDMsETMyczNdxyWxgDMwwSMwkDM50FLbFDO2ADLxIzMxcTXdxiItFmcrVmc*iozeiUmbhJGblRmI6YWYsNXZ91XXsISZ4RnchNnI6snI4FEepNnRvJXbhRnI}6ICZ1JXY0l2buJCLiQ3bvxGdpBnRvJXbhRnI6ICdlFWbBRmdh5GdhdWZi0Xf" data-annotated="true"></div></div></div>
```

(copy/paste into an editor to see the 3 divs, 2 which are embedded in the first).

I've not been able to find documentation on this encoding format (it's not plain base64 encoding) and it seems the site has gone to quite a bit of trouble to prevent easy data scraping. You may want to see if you can get this data via their API instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the highcharts plugin on an appropriate jQuery selector. The 
highcharts container can be selected using css `[data-highcharts-chart='0']`

```
library(RSelenium)
# Assume a Selenium server is accessible
# $ docker run -d -p 4444:4444 selenium/standalone-firefox:2.53.0
remDr <- remoteDriver()
remDr$open()
appURL <- "http://www.dotabuff.com/matches/2502387920"
remDr$navigate(appURL)
jsSTR <-    'var mychart = $("[data-highcharts-chart=\'0\']").highcharts();
    var xData = mychart.series[0].xData;
    var yData = mychart.series[0].yData;
    return {xdata:xData, ydata:yData};'
remDr$executeScript(jsSTR)
$xdata
[1]   60  120  180  240  300  360  420  480  540  600  660  720  780  840  900  960 1020
[18] 1080 1140 1200 1260 1320 1380 1440 1500 1560 1620 1680 1740 1800 1860

$ydata
[1]   126   203  -499   343   179   958   559  2858   496   686   483  -139  -722 -2627
[15] -2914 -2472 -1427  -940 -1973 -1494 -1418 -1281 -1286  3176  4229  8278  9257 14010
[29] 14490 14232 15150
```

Comment: This is correct, of course in js world, but the question is to parse the data after getting the html in [r]

Comment: @jbkunst I have expanded on how to use the code with R.